# How to remove item from cart on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I was wondering how to make it so that when the "x" button is clicked, the item will disappear from the cart? I'm not too familiar with javascript and was wondering if anyone can help me find a solution to this? Thank you very much in return! I will provide the code I have so far down below. Sorry if it's a little messy.

```css
.cart {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.items {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
  padding: 20px;
}

.even {
  background: #fbf7e6;
}

.infoWrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.cartSection {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.infoWrap h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.infoWrap p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #717171;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.prodTotal p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

input.qty {
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: .25em;
  margin: 1em .5em 0 0;
}

.items Img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 100px;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.remove .fa-times {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

a.remove {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #717171;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: .80;
}

a.remove:hover {
  background: #e84c40;
}


/* TOTAL */

.checkoutalign {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #fbf7e6;
  padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
}

.subtotalcf {
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.total1 {
  float: left;
}

.total1 p {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.total2 {
  float: right;
}

.total2 p {
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.totalbold p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html class="no-js">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <!--Don't forget to fill these out!-->
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="Description for site goes here." />


  <!--Links to the main Style Sheet-->
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Links to a modernizer JavaScript file that fixes a lot of issues with old browsers-->
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

  <!--Makes the site so it won't scale down on small devices -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>





  <div class="wrap cf">
    <div class="cart">
      <ul class="cartWrap">
        <li class="items even">
          <div class="infoWrap">
            <div class="cartSection info">

              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
              <h3>Grape</h3>

              <p> <input type="text" class="qty" placeholder="1" /> x $2.00</p>

            </div>


            <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
              <p>$2.00</p>
            </div>

            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
              <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="items odd">

          <div class="infoWrap">
            <div class="cartSection">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
              <h3>Orange</h3>

              <p> <input type="text" class="qty" placeholder="3" /> x $2.00</p>

            </div>


            <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
              <p>$6.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
              <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="items even">

          <div class="infoWrap">
            <div class="cartSection">

              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
              <h3>Apple</h3>

              <p> <input type="text" class="qty" placeholder="2" /> x $2.00</p>

            </div>


            <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
              <p>$4.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
              <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="items odd">
          <div class="infoWrap">
            <div class="cartSection">

              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
              <h3>Pineapple</h3>

              <p> <input type="text" class="qty" placeholder="4" /> x $2.00</p>

            </div>


            <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
              <p>$8.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
              <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="items even">
          <div class="infoWrap">
            <div class="cartSection info">

              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
              <h3>Raspberry</h3>

              <p> <input type="text" class="qty" placeholder="3" /> x $2.00</p>

            </div>


            <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
              <p>$6.00</p>
            </div>

            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
              <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: show us your js code

Comment: I would google "how to attach event on element click"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the elements with class *remove*. Then use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through all of them to attach the function to remove the closest *li* element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.remove').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.closest('li').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.cart {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.items {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
    padding: 20px;
}
  
.even {
    background: #fbf7e6;
}

.infoWrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.cartSection {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
      
.infoWrap h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.infoWrap p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #717171;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
    
.prodTotal p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

input.qty {
    width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .25em;
    margin: 1em .5em 0 0;
}

.items Img {
    float: left;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.remove .fa-times {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
}

a.remove {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #717171;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: .80;
}

a.remove:hover {
    background: #e84c40;
}

/* TOTAL */

.checkoutalign {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #fbf7e6;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
}

.subtotalcf {
    width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.total1 {
    float: left;
}

.total1 p {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.total2 {
    float: right;
}

.total2 p {
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.totalbold p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<div class="wrap cf">
  <div class="cart">
    <ul class="cartWrap">
              <li class="items even">
       <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection info">
             
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Grape</h3>
        
          <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="1"/> x $2.00</p>
                  
        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$2.00</p>
        </div>
    
            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
         </div>
         
      </li>
      <li class="items odd">
        
    <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Orange</h3>
        
           <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="3"/> x $2.00</p>
        
        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$6.00</p>
        </div>
              <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li class="items even">
        
       <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection">
         
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Apple</h3>
        
           <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="2"/> x $2.00</p>
        
        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$4.00</p>
        </div>
              <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>
      
            <li class="items odd">
             <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection">
            
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Pineapple</h3>
        
           <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="4"/> x $2.00</p>

        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$8.00</p>
        </div>
                    <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
              </div>
      </li>
      <li class="items even">
       <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection info">
             
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Raspberry</h3>
        
          <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="3"/> x $2.00</p>
                  
        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$6.00</p>
        </div>
    
            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
         </div>
         
      </li>
       
    </ul>
  </div>     
          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added Jquery in this code. any problem please let us know.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.remove').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest(".items").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.cart {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.items {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
    padding: 20px;
}
  
.even {
    background: #fbf7e6;
}

.infoWrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.cartSection {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
      
.infoWrap h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.infoWrap p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #717171;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
    
.prodTotal p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

input.qty {
    width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .25em;
    margin: 1em .5em 0 0;
}

.items Img {
    float: left;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.remove .fa-times {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
}

a.remove {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #717171;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: .80;
}

a.remove:hover {
    background: #e84c40;
}

/* TOTAL */

.checkoutalign {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #fbf7e6;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
}

.subtotalcf {
    width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.total1 {
    float: left;
}

.total1 p {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.total2 {
    float: right;
}

.total2 p {
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.totalbold p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap cf">
  <div class="cart">
    <ul class="cartWrap">
              <li class="items even">
       <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection info">
             
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Grape</h3>
        
          <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="1"/> x $2.00</p>
                  
        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$2.00</p>
        </div>
    
            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
         </div>
         
      </li>
      <li class="items odd">
        
    <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Orange</h3>
        
           <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="3"/> x $2.00</p>
        
        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$6.00</p>
        </div>
              <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li class="items even">
        
       <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection">
         
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Apple</h3>
        
           <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="2"/> x $2.00</p>
        
        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$4.00</p>
        </div>
              <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>
      
            <li class="items odd">
             <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection">
            
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Pineapple</h3>
        
           <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="4"/> x $2.00</p>

        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$8.00</p>
        </div>
                    <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
              </div>
      </li>
      <li class="items even">
       <div class="infoWrap"> 
        <div class="cartSection info">
             
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" alt="" class="itemImg" />
          <h3>Raspberry</h3>
        
          <p> <input type="text"  class="qty" placeholder="3"/> x $2.00</p>
                  
        </div>  
    
        
        <div class="prodTotal cartSection">
          <p>$6.00</p>
        </div>
    
            <div class="cartSection removeWrap">
           <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
         </div>
         
      </li>
       
    </ul>
  </div>     
          
</div>
```